# When using Chrome/Safari positioned img doesn't move

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have an absolute position img (I want to right justify it in the li).  I am using absolute positioning.  This method works fine in IE8 and FF3.6 but not as I would like in Safari and Chrome.  In the later, the img remains fixed when the div is collapsed.

I have made up a little script to demonstrate my issue:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>

      function hide()
      {
        var el = document.getElementById('collapsable');
        //el.style.visibility = "hidden";
        el.style.display = "none";

      }  // hide

      function show()
      {
        var el = document.getElementById('collapsable');
        //el.style.visibility = "visible";
        el.style.display = "inline";

      }  // show
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="button" value="Collapse" onClick='hide();' >
    <input type="button" value="Expand" onClick='show();' >
     <div id="collapsable" >
      <div>The quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</div>
      <div>The quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</div>
      <div>The quick fox jumped over the lazy brown dog</div>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li style="width:200">Item 1<span>< img src="favicon.ico" style="position:absolute; right=5px;" ></span></li>
      <li style="width:200">Item Two</li>
      <li style="width:200">Third Item</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The first thing I'd do is run your markup through a validator. You're missing some tags in there, unless this wasn't a copy and paste, in which case you should copy and paste your actual markup.

Comment: I don't see any missing tags but the Validator is not happy about all that useless spacing **within** your tags.  i.e. Change `< html >` to `<html>`, etc. etc.

Comment: I put the spaces to have it show up correctly.  When I cut/paste the whole HTML page it did not show up well in the preview.

Comment: I removed the space, except for the img tag (Stackoverflow restrictions).

Comment: change `right=5px` to `right:5px`

Comment: and could this have something to do with [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=81387)?

Comment: Instead of `right=5px;` it needs to be `right: 5px;` then it should work fine. I tried it in Chrome and it moves however many pixels off the right side of the page when I changed it to that. I didn't try it in a collapsible field, but that should fix it.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `position: absolute`?  Using `float: right` seems to work fine in both Chrome and FF @ http://jsfiddle.net/tXk2U/2/

Answer (score 0):

change `right=5px` to `right:5px`.

**EDIT**
err sorry.. give a position:relative to the li that holds the image span

Answer (score 0):

Add style `position: relative` to a wrapper element of the image.
You would probably want to add this style to the parent `<li>`.

e.g.

```
<li style="width:200; position: relative;"">Item 1
    <span>
        <img src="favicon.ico" style="position:absolute; right: 5px;" />
    </span>
</li>
```

Notice I have corrected your `right=5px;` to `right: 5px;`

Comment: If you want to better understand how positioning works, visit [CSS Positioning](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/). Though, in your case I would suggest to simply use `float: right;` to right justify the image instead of absolute positioning.

Comment: I did as suggested (added to li) and it solved the problem, as stated.  I even added to the span ("Error Mr. Robertson").  The only issue I may have with this solution is I am using jsTree and I need to test how this affects how jsTree renders (I just ran it in the debugger, for a quick check) and it seems to do no harm.  This was only in Chrome, I don't have Safari on me right now.